# Do we accept grawlixes anywhere on the site?

Tags: discussion

In a comment, a user used the &%@# symbols to "hide" the swear word:

```
wont that F@£% up my Laptop –  t01vO 15 mins ago
```

My reply was:

```
No, why would it? Also, please try to use appropriate language - mess up would be fine?
```

Especially this instance, where it was obvious what the word was, I disliked it. I personally don't like so see a reputable site (We're not ubuntu forums) with bad language on it - even if it is 'Hidden'.

Is it acceptable for people to use grawlixes anywhere on the site - i.e. Questions/Answers/Comments or Meta, Chat, Profiles or similar, and if so, which?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, but it is harder to enforce than real swears.

It still means the same thing, and is recognized as the same - so ♥'s or ★'s are not going to make it any better.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233

---

Profiles, are a entirely different matter:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251442/how-to-deal-with-user-who-use-abusive-words-in-about-me-section

---

Also note that comments that contain certain swear words are automatically deleted when flagged.

And If it fits this description:

> it is offensive, abusive, or hate speech This question contains
>   content that a reasonable person would deem inappropriate for
>   respectful discourse.

or for comments:

> rude or offensive

Flag them.

Or, if there is just one edit it out.

---

https://askubuntu.com/help/behavior

> Be nice.
>
> Civility is required at all times; rudeness will not be tolerated.
>   Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you
>   because we’re all here to learn, together. Be tolerant of others who
>   may not know everything you know, and bring your sense of humor.
>
> Please note that expletives are not allowed. If you use expletives on
>   this site, you may be issued a warning or a suspension.

---

Also there are cases - were they can be used fine, **Only** because they happen to be the name of a file, or program, or part of a website title. Example:

[can't run this shell script (get-sh1t-done)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50513/cant-run-this-shell-script)

Comment: The other answer has more upvotes http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22246/213575

Comment: But this answer came straight from Jeff, so it doesn’t matter if more people voted for that one.

Comment: "bring your sense of humor" <--- I can do it and at the same time swear, you know?

Comment: and I will flag your comments that contain swears ;p anyway if you can't get more creative than masking out letters on certain words, that isn't very funny

Comment: that answer mostly refers to the fact that normal words can be used in such a way, and we aren't going to ban every honey bear biscuit feeder, and pony pouncing phrase, also like shog said - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites/22246#comment45727_22246

Answer (score -4):

Yup.

Comment: All of the places I asked, or just some?